# How to unit test a method that uses javafx file chooser

Tags: java, unit-testing, javafx, filechooser

I want to write a unit test for my save and load methods but the methods use file chooser and I do not know how to simulate those being used in a unit test.

My load and save methods are below

Apparently I need to add more detail but i have summed up my situation concisely.

```java
public static String load() throws IOException {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();

        // Define extension filters
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter txtFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter odtFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("ODT Files (*.odt)", "*.odt");
        fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(txtFilter, odtFilter);

        File file = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

        // Chose an appropriate method to load the file contents
        if (file != null) {
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter selectedFilter = fc.getSelectedExtensionFilter();
            if (selectedFilter == txtFilter) {
                return readTxt(file);
            } else if (selectedFilter == odtFilter) {
                return readOdt(file);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

// Displays a save file dialog
// Does not return any value
public static void save(String text) throws IOException {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();

        // Define extension filters
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter txtFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter pdfFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF Files (*.pdf)", "*.pdf");
        fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(txtFilter, pdfFilter);

        File file = fc.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (file != null) {
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter selectedFilter = fc.getSelectedExtensionFilter();

            if (selectedFilter == txtFilter) {
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                writer.write(text);
                writer.close();
            } else if (selectedFilter == pdfFilter) {
                savePdf(text, file);
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

are you sure you want to unit test this method?  There is no logic here.  But if you are in some terrible situation where you absolutely have to, you will need to create a factory for creating FileChooser objects, then pass an instance of that factory to this method, then in your unit tests create a stub version of FileChooser class (extend FileChooser) which will will override methods of FileChooser which are called in your methods with empty stubs.  You can also use a mocking library like Mockito to reduce amount of code you need to write, perhaps.

Comment: Just a point of interest: JavaFX's [`FileChooser`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) is `final`.